# How to iterate through all foreign keys pointed at an object in Django without using _set notation?

Tags: python, django, inheritance, foreign-keys

I am fairly new to Django, but I am working on an application that will follow a CPQ flow or Configure, Price, Quote. The user should select the product they would like to configure as well as the options to go with it. Once selected, the program should query an external pricing database to calculate price. From there the program should output the pricing & text data onto a PDF quote. I was able to get the application working using the specific product inheriting from a base product class. The issue is now that I've created a second product child class, I cannot use a singular "related_name". I've omitted the lists associated with the drop down fields to help with readability, but I've posted my models.py file below.

Is there a way I can iterate through Product objects that are pointing to a Quote object with a foreign key? A lot of answers I've found on SO relating to this were able to be solved either by specifying the "_set" or "related_name". I've seen other answers use the select_related() method, however, I can't seem to get the query right as the program won't know which set it needs to look at. A quote could have any mix of product instances tied to it, so am unsure how to handle that query. Again, I have been using django under 6 months, so I am a bit green. I am not sure if I am just not fundamentally understanding the big picture here. I thought about instead of using inheritance, to make Product a standalone class and to save the Compact or WRC info to it so I could just use one "related_name", but also thought that would just create another nested layer that would still fail.

Any help would be very appreciated! I've definitely hit the wall.

models.py

class Quote(models.Model):

```
project_name = models.CharField(max_length=256,blank=True)
customer_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=256,blank=True)
customer_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=256,blank=True)
company_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
address1 = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, help_text ="Address")
address2 = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
city = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, default="")
state = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, default="")
zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, default="")
country = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, default="")
phone = PhoneField(blank=True)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=254,blank=True)
grand_total = models.FloatField(default=0)
create_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
```

class Product(models.Model):

```
class Meta:
    abstract = True

price = models.FloatField(default=0)
total_price = models.FloatField(default=0)
quantity = models.IntegerField()
quote = models.ForeignKey('quote.Quote', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

class Compact(Product):

```
base_size = models.CharField(choices=size, max_length = 256)
filter = models.CharField(choices=filter_list, max_length = 256)
product_name = models.CharField(max_length=256,default="Compact")
```

class WRC(Product):

```
base_size = models.CharField(choices=size, max_length = 256)
construction = models.CharField(choices=construction_list, max_length = 256)
outlet = models.CharField(choices=outlet_list, max_length = 256)
product_name = models.CharField(max_length=256,default="WRC")
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out my issue, but wanted to answer in case someone came across a similar problem as myself. I was able to get get all product objects attached to a quote instance dynamically by modifying the get_context_data() method of my QuoteDetailView. I also needed to use the django library NestedObjects from django.contrib.admin.utils to grab all related objects to the quote instance. I also added a timestamp field to the Product class to be able to sort them. QuoteDetailView copied below.

class QuoteDetailView(FormMixin,DetailView):

```
model = Quote
form_class = ProductSelectForm



def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ### collects related objects from quote 
    collector = NestedObjects(using=DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS)
    collector.collect([kwargs['object']])
        ### slice off first element which is the quote itself
    related_objects = collector.nested()
    related_objects = related_objects[1:]
        ### get context data for qoute object 
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['now'] = timezone.now()
        ### if number of list items is above 0, then add them to the context
        ### and sort by timestamp
    if len(related_objects) != 0:
        context['items'] = sorted(related_objects[0], key=lambda x: x.timestamp)

    return context
```